# Help with Riemann Lebesgue Lemma Proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I know there are many proofs out there, but I was asked to prove this in a particular way. I'm stuck on this step:

**Note:** Let $[a.b]$ be compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g$ be a continuous function from $[a.b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

> If $g_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions from $[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \int_a^b [g_n(x)-g(x)] \exp(i \lambda x) \,\mathrm dx = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b |g_n(x)-g(x)|\,\mathrm dx=0$.

I'm pretty sure the proof shouldn't be difficult, but I'm stumped. I think I should use compactness and continuity somewhere to show that $g_n\rightarrow g$ by passing to subsequences if necessary, but then I'm wary of my approach.

Comment: What relation between $g_n$ and $g$?

Comment: I presume you made a typo in the first integral? Should it be $(g_n(x)-g(x))\exp(i\lambda x)$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong in my logic: We should have that $g_n$ converges to $g$. This is because $[a,b]$ is a compact interval so then $g_n$ converges to $g$ by sequential compactness, passing to subsequences if necessary. Also, we should furthermore have $\int g_n(x)$ converges to $\int g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I've pondered that myself, but it indeed says on my sheet here that it is $g_n(x) exp(i\lambda x)$.

Comment: Pointwise convergence is not enough, even on compact intervals. Your sheet is clearly wrong, as seen by applying the alleged result to both $g$ and $h(x) := g(x) +1$. Unfortunately I'm not in a position right now to investigate possible fixes of what is on your sheet.

Comment: I believe, with that in mind, I can safely assume that the sheet most likely has a typo. I'll go ahead and change the problem statement accordingly.